# Substitute Column name in dynamic queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamicquery

I have a procedure , in which i am receiving a parameter column name and creating the dynamic query by substituting column name.

when i am directly running this dynamic query its working fine.

```
declare @a datetime,
@b varchar(50) ='CREATED_DATE',--column name
@query varchar(500);
select  @a= CONVERT(datetime,LAST_RUN_PROC,121) from TEST_TABLE_MASTER


exec( 'select '+@b+' from TEST1 where '+@b+' = '+''''+@a+'''' )
```

But when i am storing query in a variable and then executing,its showing error.
Below code showing error

```
declare @a datetime,
@b varchar(50) ='CREATED_DATE',--column name
@query varchar(500);
select  @a= CONVERT(datetime,LAST_RUN_PROC,121) from TEST_TABLE_MASTER

SET @query=  'select '+@b+' from TEST1 where '+@b+' = '+''''+@a+'''' --this line showing error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

exec (@query)
```

I got stuck here.please help

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: `'select ' + @b + ' from TEST1 where ' + @b + ' = '
            + '''' + CONVERT(varchar(20),@a, 121) + ''''`

Comment: its not working,showing the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Concatenating SQL string is not the best idea, because of multiple `''''` needed. It is error-prone and hard to debug.
2. Use correct types (table name, column name) - `SYSNAME`, query -`NVARCHAR(MAX)`.
3. You can use `REPLACE` placeholder to fill values or pass them as parameter to `EXEC dbo.sp_executesql`.
4. Always quote table/column names.
5. `SELECT  @a= CONVERT(datetime, LAST_RUN_PROC,121) FROM TEST_TABLE_MASTER;` will set `@a` last read value from table, you should add `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY`.

Code:

```
DECLARE @a DATETIME,
        @b SYSNAME            ='CREATED_DATE',
        @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT  @a= CONVERT(datetime, LAST_RUN_PROC,121) FROM TEST_TABLE_MASTER;

SET @query = 
   N'SELECT <col_name>
     FROM TEST1
     WHERE <col_name> = ''<col_value>'';';

SET @query = REPLACE(@query, '<col_name>', QUOTENAME(@b));     
SET @query = REPLACE(@query, '<col_value>', @a);  

--SELECT @query;

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
     @query;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ded85/6/0)**</kbd>

Recommended version with parameter passing and `dbo.sp_executesql` instead of `EXEC`:

```
DECLARE @a DATETIME,
        @b SYSNAME            ='CREATED_DATE',
        @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @a= LAST_RUN_PROC FROM TEST_TABLE_MASTER;

SET @query = 
   N'SELECT <col_name>
     FROM TEST1
     WHERE <col_name> = @a;';

SET @query = REPLACE(@query, '<col_name>', QUOTENAME(@b));     

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
     @query
     ,N'@a DATETIME'
     ,@a;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ded85/9/0)**</kbd>

**Warning:**

Using Dynamic-SQL is great resposibility. If you don't understand it, don't use Dynamic-SQL at all.

**EDIT:**

I've managed to run your example, but I strongly recommend to use one of the solution above:

```
SET @query=  'select '+@b+' from TEST1 where '+@b+' = '+''''+CONVERT(varchar(19),@a, 121)+''''
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo3`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ded85/16/0)**</kbd>

Comment: thanks for the answer.its working fine.Do you have any idea why my query is not working( just for curiosity ) ;)

Comment: Thanks Man ,You are a Champ. I will use the above solution.thanks